# Starting multiple instances of a service in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I was wondering if it is possible to start multiple instances of one service in angular.
I am using the same service in different directives and controllers but in one case I would like to use the service twice (or more) in one controller where it makes a second instance. Is this possible without having to make an identical second service?

I made a very simplified [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/brokenhip/j9f9ybLy/1/):

So depending on an attribute of my directive I would like to create a new instance of the service (in this case that would make two stand alone counters)

As I don't want to change to much existing code I tried a far from perfect solution with arrays. See [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/brokenhip/j9f9ybLy/3/) Is this a very bad way? Could it be improved? **Will it make everything slower** (as everything is now stored in an array in an array)?

Comment: Can you store the result of the computations in the directive's scope instead of the service's scope?

Answer (score 2):

You can use use your **factory** as an API to return a collection of objects with getter and setter methods.

Then, you can **encapsulate** the creation of an instance into a getter method. You will have a safe and proper way to handle multiple service.

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service(){

    //Create our userFactory
    function Service(id){
      this.value = 0;
      console.log('Service n°' + id);
    };


    function getCounter(){
      return this.value;
    }


    function count(){
      ++this.value;
    }


    //Set method by prototyping
    Service.prototype.getCounter = getCounter;
    Service.prototype.count = count;

    return {
      //Use get method to return a new instance of our factory
      get: function(){
        //Pass random id to make difference between services
        return new Service(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100));
      }
    }

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Service', Service);

})();
```

**Directive**

```
(function(){

  function directive(Service) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<h1>{{counter()}}</h1><button ng-click="count()">count</button>',
        scope: {
            hasInstance: '@'
        },
        resolve: {
            hasInstance: function(){
                return $scope.hasInstance;
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, $element, $attrs){
            //Retrieve new instance of Service
            var service = Service.get();
            scope.counter = function(){
                return service.getCounter();
            }
            scope.count = function(){
                service.count();
            }
        }
    }
  }

angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('directive', directive);

})();
```

You can see the [**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tSg6HZq0IcWyB4elCff5?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was searching. But I am afraid that this would ask for a lot of changes as the service is already used in a lot of places.
So I adjusted the service so it works with arrays. I guess that's a dirty solution and only so many different instances can be made as I hardcode in the service but it does make that I wouldn't need to change code anywhere. here is my [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/brokenhip/j9f9ybLy/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Hey @BrokenHip Development,

What is it you are trying to achieve exactly with two instances of a service? I think your approach might not be quite as angular intended.

I don't think it's really the intention to couple a service to a directive instance or any directive. A directive should ideally be it's own standalone entity that can be dropped in and out of your application with the potential of being used in another application etc.

For instance, you have a counter in your example. Each directive maintains it's own scope which could hold this value. Your controller would also be able to see this value either through directive attributes or you could communicate with a controller using an event driven approach. Ideally, your directives should have no dependencies on other controllers and services within your app and only the core components of angular.

Hope that helps you out a little!

Comment: In our application the directive uses the service so we can show the list of active persons at every part of our application so that is why it is coupled to the service. The problem is now that on one page we would like to show two different lists of active persons. What explains why I would like two instances of the service. The aplication is already for almost a year under development and this is one of it core futures that is used all most everywhere what makes it to much work to remake everything.

Comment: The directive can still make use of the service but the directive should not be coupled to the service. 

A directive is a view component, it shouldn't contain any logic or internal invocations of services. If it needs to grab a list of items, these should be exposed to a directive via the parent controller through directive attributes. If the list is globally available across your application then look to make use of `$rootScope` if that is possible.

What you are trying to do with two instances of a service goes against the principles of angular and isn't really possible.

Comment: You could have two instances of the list within your controller by resolving the list in your router and then creating two instances of the list within your controller by using angulars clone functionality.

Comment: I wonder if the way I now solved it see [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/brokenhip/j9f9ybLy/3/) won't slow everything down and use a more resources. Does an array in an array make everything slower? I know it wasn't the best solution but I could make it fast and if it doesn't cost extra resources I'm fine with that.

Comment: It shouldn't slow things noticeably, you can always do some profiling in the debugger if you're concerned about it. However, it would still be ideal to decouple your directives from your services and move any invocation into the controller working off two instances in the controller. Going further down this route could make your directives more complex to maintain later down the line.